# Force play mp3 instead of download

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link say http://www.example.com/test (Please note: This is not a direct mp3 url)

When I hit this url, it initiates a download of mp3 file.

Right now I am using this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/test"><img src="img/play22.png" width="20" height="20">
```

This is downloading the mp3 file instead of playing.

My aim is to play that mp3 in new window with a player on my site by clicking an image instead of downloading that file.

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**: Like I mentioned above I don't have direct mp3 link. The link I have (say www.example.com/test) is just a url which redirects to the exact mp3 link (say www.example.com/sounds/abc.mp3) and then I get option for download that mp3.

The answers I am getting is to play an mp3 if I have the mp3 file or I know the direct url of mp3 file.

The solution I am looking for will be like. It first downloads that mp3 in a temp folder and then plays it. The file will be deleted from temp folder once music player is closed.

Comment: If you link directly to the file, the user has the choice of downloading or playing it depending on their browser settings. If you want to only ever stream the MP3, you'd have to either build an mp3 player app from scratch, or use an existing one; but that's beyond the scope of a question like this.

Comment: Look into the [`audio` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) which (in some browsers) can play the MP3 for you inline (others require for example ogg format instead).

Comment: Please read the comments I edited in my question Ken and BFDatabaseAdmin

Answer (score 2):

You may use HTML5:

```
<audio src="/test/audio.ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio player, please upgrade your browser.
</audio>
```

Or use a cross browser solution:
http://mediaelementjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

**HTML**

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com/test">
```

Check embed tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp).