# When streaming response in Flask file unplayable

Tags: python, flask, ffmpeg, subprocess

I currently have a function that runs ffmpeg enconder on a flv stream from youtube.

```
def console(cmd, add_newlines=False):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        data = p.stdout.readline()
        if add_newlines:
            data += str('\n')
        yield data

        p.poll()
        if isinstance(p.returncode, int):
            if p.returncode > 0:
                # return code was non zero, an error?
                print 'error:', p.returncode
            break
```

This works fine when I run the ffmpeg command and have it output to a file.  The file is playable.

```
mp3 = console('ffmpeg -i "%s" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -f mp3 test.mp3' % video_url, add_newlines=True)
```

But when I have ffmpeg output to stdout via `-` instead of `test.mp3`, and stream that response.  The file streams fine, is the correct size.  But does not play correctly.  Sounds chopy, and when I check the properties of the file it doesn't show the data of it as it does with test.mp3

```
@app.route('/test.mp3')
def generate_large_mp3(path):
    mp3 = console('ffmpeg -i "%s" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -f mp3 -' % video_url, add_newlines=True)
    return Response(stream_with_context(mp3), mimetype="audio/mpeg3",
                   headers={"Content-Disposition":
                                "attachment;filename=test.mp3"})
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What is `console` function? Is it from a third-party library?

Comment: the console function is defined in the question, it is to use ```subprocess``` from python to run ffmpeg to do the conversion.

Comment: unrelated to you mp3 case: (1) `.readline()` returns a string with the newline already (unless the last line doesn't end with a newline). (2) `str('\n')` is pointless: `'\n'` by itself is already `str` object; unless there is `from __future__ import unicode_literals` on Python 2. (3) Don't call `.poll()` in a loop: here's a [correct way to read text lines from a subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

Comment: `add_newlines=True` should corrupt your binary mp3 data unless mp3 allows to double all `'\n'` in the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. It seems you copied this `console` function from somewhere. The main problem is that this function is designed to work on text output. The command that you are running with ffmpeg will dump the binary raw mp3 data to stdout, so reading that output as if it was a text file with `readlines()` will not work. The concept of lines does not exist at all in the mp3 binary stream.

I have adapted your `console()` function to work on binary streams. Here is my version:

```
def console(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        data = p.stdout.read()
        yield data

        p.poll()
        if isinstance(p.returncode, int):
            if p.returncode > 0:
                # return code was non zero, an error?
                print 'error:', p.returncode
            break
```

Note that I have removed all the references to newline handling, and also replaced `readline()` with `read()`.

With this version I get the streaming to work. I hope this helps!

*Edit*: You could force the response to go out in chunks of a specified size by calling `read(N)` with `N` being the chunk size. For a given audio bitrate, you can calculate the size in bytes for a chunk of audio with a duration of say, 5 seconds, and then stream 5 second chunks.

Comment: unfortunately this half works, the file is playable but It does what I currently have where it downloads the entire file before sending it to the user.  What I'm trying to avoid here is when a large mp3 is put the client has to wait for the entire song to convert before sending it.

Comment: I think "streaming" in this context can be interpreted as two different things. On the server, streaming means that you can provide the response in chunks. That's the part I answered here, and I believe that is the "half" that works. The part that remains, is to make the browser instantiate an audio player and start playing while the response is still streaming. For that, you need to embed an audio player, I think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450930/force-play-mp3-instead-of-download for some ideas.

Comment: (1) `while True: data = p.stdout.read()` is wrong. `.read()` won't return until EOF. OP could use `os.read(p.stdout.fileno(), 8192)` instead (`os.read()` returns as soon as there is any data available). (2) don't call `p.poll()`, use `if not data: break` instead.

Comment: @nadermx awesome! But do note the comment by @J.F.Sebastian regarding the potential for the `read()` call to block. To avoid that, you can do what he says, or else use a block size that is a multiple of the mp3 frame size for your chosen bitrate.

Answer (score 2):

To stream mp3 content generated by a subprocess using flask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from functools import partial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

from flask import Flask, Response  # $ pip install flask

mp3file = 'test.mp3'
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """<!doctype html>
<title>Play {mp3file}</title>
<audio controls autoplay >
    <source src="{mp3file}" type="audio/mp3" >
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>""".format(mp3file=mp3file)


@app.route('/' + mp3file)
def stream():
    process = Popen(['cat', mp3file], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
    read_chunk = partial(os.read, process.stdout.fileno(), 1024)
    return Response(iter(read_chunk, b''), mimetype='audio/mp3')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Replace `['cat', mp3file]` with your `ffmpeg` command that writes mp3 content to its stdout.

Comment: Thanks for this code!  It is just what I needed. Cheers!.